# How to control transparent depth intensity to get even gradient based on another object?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, light, transparency, shaders

So I'm trying to make a configurable way of revealing something inside of any object with corresponding node group. Whatever I did I couldn't get a nice gradient between pink and grey area which I certainly want.

And as I see it, the gradient shape has to be based on shape of the transparent plane, but gradient projects on cube with it's coordinates and choosing object-->object-plane didn't really help, because the gradient has to move with the plane and I would like to make it without using drivers if possible.

Also I want the gradient to repeat shape of the plane along edges(it can be a rectangle with round corners for example or a triangle).

Another problem is that if object placed inside of the cube emits light at certain angles it makes clear that there's a transparent plane floating in front of the cube, because the light stops for some reason, that I don't understand.

[image: node setup]
[image: plane1]
[image: plane2]

Here's my [blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45596)